# Force function to pick a dark shade from image instaed of Light One

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, uicolor

I have created this function to pick color from image.

```
fun getMainColor(img: Bitmap): Int {
    val newImg = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, 1, 1, true)
    val color = newImg.getPixel(0, 0)
    newImg.recycle()
    return color
}
```

But it usually chooses a Light Shade color that makes the UI so Ugly, I want it to Choose a dark shade from the image. How Could I do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Palette API](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/palette-colors) is good solution for find the colors from the Image
> with multiple [choices](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette).

Comment: Can you write the code that i should use instead of above code

Comment: @ShahZamanRai - Please go through this example for more details - https://www.section.io/engineering-education/extracting-colors-from-image-using-palette-api-in-android/